# Could not connect to the R session on RStudio server - When running RStudio as a custom app in AML getting this error for after enabled copilot

Tags: r, docker, azure-machine-learning-service, rstudio-server, github-copilot

We've set up RStudio on an Azure Machine Learning (AML) compute instance using a custom application and the rocker/RStudio Docker image. In order to activate copilot functionality, I referred to the [user guide](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/tools/copilot.html). However, after completing the outlined steps, I encountered an error as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

How can Copilot be activated in RStudio running on an Azure Machine Learning Compute Instance to prevent encountering this error?